# Ball Collision with a man

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection

I'm making a game where you're supposed to dodge bouncing balls coming from the left side of the screen. The problem I'm having is with the collision between the ball and the man. I want the "bottom" of the ball to hit the man so it creates an effect of "crushing" the man, thereby ending the game. I am using adobe flash professional CC (Creative Cloud).

**EDIT:** I added a new CollisionTest.as class to my game and followed a "perfect-pixel" collision test function, but it doesn't seem to work? Any ideas why?

```
package 
{
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class CollisionTest 
{
    // vars
    private var _returnValue:Boolean;

    private var _onePoint:Point;
    private var _twoPoint:Point;

    private var _oneRectangle:Rectangle;
    private var _twoRectangle:Rectangle;

    private var _oneClipBmpData:BitmapData;
    private var _twoClipBmpData:BitmapData;

    private var _oneOffset:Matrix;
    private var _twoOffset:Matrix;

    /**
     * Simple collision test. Use this for objects that are not rotated.
     * @param   clip1   Takes DisplayObjectContainer as argument. Can be a Sprite, MovieClip, etc.
     * @param   clip2   Takes DisplayObjectContainer as argument. Can be a Sprite, MovieClip, etc.
     * @return  Collision True/False
     */
    public function simple(clip1:DisplayObjectContainer, clip2:DisplayObjectContainer):Boolean
    {
        _returnValue = false;

        _oneRectangle = clip1.getBounds(clip1);
        _oneClipBmpData = new BitmapData(_oneRectangle.width, _oneRectangle.height, true, 0);
        _oneClipBmpData.draw(clip1);

        _twoRectangle = clip2.getBounds(clip2);
        _twoClipBmpData = new BitmapData(_twoRectangle.width, _twoRectangle.height, true, 0);
        _twoClipBmpData.draw(clip2);

        _onePoint = new Point(clip1.x, clip1.y)
        _twoPoint =  new Point(clip2.x, clip2.y)

        if (_oneClipBmpData.hitTest(_onePoint, 255, _twoClipBmpData, _twoPoint, 255))
        {
            _returnValue = true;
        }

        return _returnValue;
    }

    /**
     * Complex collision test. Use this for objects that are rotated, scaled, skewed, etc
     * @param   clip1   Takes DisplayObjectContainer as argument. Can be a Sprite, MovieClip, etc.
     * @param   clip2   Takes DisplayObjectContainer as argument. Can be a Sprite, MovieClip, etc.
     * @return  Collision True/False
     */
    public function complex(clip1:DisplayObjectContainer, clip2:DisplayObjectContainer):Boolean
    {
        _returnValue = false;

        _twoRectangle = clip1.getBounds(clip1);
        _oneOffset = clip1.transform.matrix;
        _oneOffset.tx = clip1.x - clip2.x;
        _oneOffset.ty = clip1.y - clip2.y;  

        _twoClipBmpData = new BitmapData(_twoRectangle.width, _twoRectangle.height, true, 0);
        _twoClipBmpData.draw(clip1, _oneOffset);        

        _oneRectangle = clip2.getBounds(clip2);
        _oneClipBmpData = new BitmapData(_oneRectangle.width, _oneRectangle.height, true, 0);

        _twoOffset = clip2.transform.matrix;
        _twoOffset.tx = clip2.x - clip2.x;
        _twoOffset.ty = clip2.y - clip2.y;  

        _oneClipBmpData.draw(clip2, _twoOffset);

        _onePoint = new Point(_oneRectangle.x, _oneRectangle.y);
        _twoPoint = new Point(_twoRectangle.x, _twoRectangle.y);

        if(_oneClipBmpData.hitTest(_onePoint, 255, _twoClipBmpData, _twoPoint, 255))
        {
            _returnValue = true;
            trace("collision detected!");
        }

        _twoClipBmpData.dispose();
        _oneClipBmpData.dispose();

        return _returnValue;
    }

}
}
```

The two parameters I input are the ball and the man, and the collision doesn't work at all. I tried debugging the code, but I can't find the problem. However, when I make the two parameters between the ball and the non-movable container, the collision works?

Is it because my man moves that the collision doesn't work? What should I change in the code above?

Thank-you in advance.

Comment: You're using hitTestObject which uses the bounds of the object. This means that instead of testing with the circle, it's testing with the rectangle that circumscribes the circle. You may want to look into Grant Skinner's Shape-based hit detection: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2005/10/source_code_sha.html

Comment: Thanks but is there a site where it returns true when the two objects hit, not the intersection of the collision.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean is there a site where there's a shape-based hit detection code that tests two objects, not returning intersection of the two objects that collide, but rather a boolean if the two objects collide or not?

Comment: In Grant Skinner's library, if `checkForCollision` returns `null`, that's the same as `false`. Likewise, if it returns a rectangle at all, it's the same as `true`.

Comment: could I use hitTestPoint with the top of the man's head?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to use `hitTestPoint` since you're checking for collision between two objects and `hitTestPoint` would only return true if precise circumstances are met. Can you explain why you don't think you can use Grant Skinner's library?

Comment: The problem is that I want the ball to touch only the man's head, having it touch any other part of the man's body and making him die would only make the game seem nonrealistic.

Comment: In that case, make sure that the man's head is an object parented under the "man" object. This will allow you to check collision with *just* the head. Let's say I have an object `man` and a child object of that `man` is an object `head`. I can then call `checkForCollision(ball, man.getChildByName("head"));`

Comment: The above didn't work, and checkForCollision doesn't seem to work with  game, the function comes up with errors with the getBounds(_root), the bounds.xmax (when xmax isn't even defined?). What should I do?

Comment: @Marcela Could you read the above comments and help please?

Comment: Sorry, but it's not easy to decipher what the issue is from the information provided. In your code above you say that "it doesn't work" and that you debugged it, but you didn't explain what debugging turned up. In your comment above you said you have an error with `getBounds`. You may want to completely overhaul the question and zero in on the exact issue.